# What does this error mean as an output from the rails command?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows

```
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in 
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
from C:/RAILSI~1/INTERE~1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\RAILSI~1\INTERE~1\config>
```

This is all the output I could grab because DOS doesn't scroll up.

I am trying to port a rails app from Linux to windows. The only thing different is this app uses mysql. So In installed the MYSQL gem. Both using ruby 191, both using rails 329.

I have done some digging and it seams its because the mysql.dll I put in there is version 5.0 when the mysql gem was compiled for 6.0. Client 6.0 doesn't seem to exist.

I wouldn't normally ask but I am at my wit's end with this.

Comment: FYI, here is how to set your console buffer in Windows: http://superuser.com/a/161188/42660

Comment: Command windows absolutely "scroll up" if you have the buffer set to a reasonable size. Even if it didn't, you could pipe stdout/stderr to a file.

Comment: I tried that, I tried rails s -p 8080 > out.log its empty, god I hate windows.

Comment: P.s changing the buffer size did nothing too, I looked at that first.

Comment: There is no MySQL 6.0 wth?

Comment: Is there any more detail in: `log/development.log`?  I also seem to recall that 1.9.1 is not ideal, you may wish to upgrade to ruby 1.9.2/1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 2.9.x of the MySQL gem, it was built against MySQL 6.0 and you can download the correct version of the C Connector from the MySQL web site. After installing the `mysql` gem, it should have given you a URL to go to to download the correct version. However, if you installed `mysql` using `bundle install` then the post-install message may not have been displayed.

http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/

There's the URL to grab the binary library as a ZIP file.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

In case the first link doesn't work, there's the URL with all of the available C Connector downloads. You want **Windows (x86, 32-bit), ZIP Archive** (the second one; the one where the filename does not end in *vs2005*).

If the MySQL library still comes up as a mismatch, do a `gem list mysql` to get the version that is installed, then uninstall and reinstall the gem manually:

```
gem uninstall mysql

gem install -v=x.x.x mysql
```

Replace `x.x.x` with the version number that was reported previously. After the gem is installed, it should give you the URL of the C Connector you need to install.